# What is the point of closing a question that is asked, answered, got positive reception, and has an answer accepted by questioner?

Tags: discussion

What is the point of closing the question that is asked, answered, got positive reception by users, and has an answer accepted by questioner? The case in point is the following question and answer: [Most serious and significant attacks on Tor users have been done via malware. What is the state of the art technology to defend against this?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/most-serious-and-significant-attacks-on-tor-users-have-been-done-via-malware-wh)

It gives the impression that there is a couple of over zealous folks who may have excessive negative views, impertinent to other users by the record of their negative voting, and last but not the least an overbearing attitude.

Comment: Could just be a power trip.  "Who watches the watchers?" comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the point of closing the question that is asked, answered, got
>   positive reception by users, and has an answer accepted by questioner?

For the same reason you'd close an offtopic question that hadn't been answered yet; because we want the information on this site to be focused, and don't want the site cluttered up with questions about general security topics (for which there are other stack exchange sites where the user will likely get higher quality answers). The more offtopic questions there are, the more they distract from the sites main topic.

> It gives the impression that there are some over zealous folks who may
>   have excessive negative views and impertinent to other users by the
>   record of their negative votings.

This seems a little unfair; this is often a problem on SE sites, and something we should try to fix if it happens on Tor.SE, but I see no indication that this is what happened here. As far as I can tell, the question really is offtopic.

Comment: Rolled back to the quote I was actually responding to to prevent the context from changing.

Comment: Dear Sam, With all do respect, I disagree with your answer in this case. Warm Regards,

Comment: @Roya What part do you disagree with? Do you think that question is on topic and shouldn't have been closed? If so, please move to re-open it, and let the community decide.

Comment: Dear Sam, If you do not mind, please uupdate your answer to match the edited version of the question. Warm Regards,

Comment: @Roya I just want it to be clear that I was responding to the original question, not the edited one. I'll think about the added statements, and update if I have anything to add. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: This is a good reminder that when editing someone's question it is not fair to change the intent.  Maybe clarify language, correct a title, add and/or remove tags.  But it shouldn't be to take them off the rails and into the weeds.  That being said, Google can still find answers regardless of whether the question is accurate.  Remember, this is a database that is very visible to Google, and good answers are useful even when slightly off-topic.